# Customize ToolBar Title and Menu (v7.widget.Toolbar)

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I have a toolbar in my app defined with v7.widget.Toolbar

**Layout:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme"/>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

**v21/styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ToolBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@color/sky_blue</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>


    <item name="titleTextAppearance">@style/TitleActionBarStyle</item>

    </style>
    <!-- action bar title text -->
    <style name="TitleActionBarStyle">
        <!--Any text styling can be done here-->
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">10dp</item>
    </style>
```

And what I get with these styles is ...

[image]

The background of the toolbar is correct (sky_blue), the text of the menu is correct (white), but the size of the title is not 10dp, it is bigger.

So, I would like to know how to change size, style, color of the title of the ToolBar and if its posible how can I customize the menu?

Comment: For fonts, use `sp` unit